# Login with facebook, store data in MySQL, render profile and admin panel

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, session

Post this question in "[codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159858/login-with-facebook-store-data-in-mysql-render-profile-and-admin-panel)" without any help, I hope you can help me on this page.

I have an online catalog on which I need the customers to save their favorite products and shipping addresses. I want to manage the access with Facebook for security of all. I also need a section for the admin, to see some information in the database.

I want to know if this is safe. I want a basic "system" of user control and administration panel. I want to continue with the second part but I need to be sure that I'm going the right way.

**entrar.php (login)**

```
<?php
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

// #################### Facebook config #################### //
require_once 'includes/facebook/autoload.php';

// Include required libraries
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

// Configuration and setup Facebook SDK
$appId                  = '123456789'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret          = '123456789'; //Facebook App Secret
$redirectURL        = 'http://localhost/facebook/entrar.php'; //Callback URL
$fbPermissions  = array('email');  //Optional permissions

$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
));

// Get redirect login helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// Try to get access token
try {
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    }else{
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
    exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
    exit;
}

// #################### User class #################### //
require_once 'includes/meekrodb.php';

class User {
    function checkUser($userData = array()){
        if(!empty($userData)){
            // Check whether user data already exists in database
            $prevQuery = DB::query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_fb = %s", $userData['id_fb']);
            $counter = DB::count();
            if($counter > 0){
            // Update user data if already exists
            DB::update('usuarios', array(
                'nombre' => $userData['nombre'],
                'apellido' => $userData['apellido'],
                'email' => $userData['email'],
                'genero' => $userData['genero'],
                'idioma' => $userData['idioma'],
                'imagen' => $userData['imagen'],
                'url' => $userData['url'],
                'modificado' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
                ), "id_fb = %s", $userData['id_fb']
            );
            }else{
            // Insert user data
            DB::insert('usuarios', array(
                'id_fb' => $userData['id_fb'],
                'nombre' => $userData['nombre'],
                'apellido' => $userData['apellido'],
                'email' => $userData['email'],
                'genero' => $userData['genero'],
                'idioma' => $userData['idioma'],
                'imagen' => $userData['imagen'],
                'url' => $userData['url'],
                'creado' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                'modificado' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
            ));
            }
            // Get user data from the database
            $result = DB::queryRaw("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_fb = %s", $userData['id_fb']);
            $userData = $result->fetch_assoc();
        }       
        // Return user data
        return $userData;
    }
}

// #################### Goo! #################### //
if(isset($accessToken)){
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }else{
        // Put short-lived access token in session
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // Set default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // Redirect the user back to the same page if url has "code" parameter in query string
    if(isset($_GET['code'])){
        header('Location:'.$redirectURL);
        exit;
    }

    // Getting user facebook profile info
    try {
        $profileRequest = $fb->get('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture,link');
        $fbUserProfile = $profileRequest->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
        session_destroy();
        // Redirect user back to app login page
        header('Location:'.$redirectURL);
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
        exit;
    }

    // Initialize User class
    $user = new User();

    // Insert or update user data to the database
    $fbUserData = array(
        'id_fb'         => $fbUserProfile['id'],
        'nombre'        => $fbUserProfile['first_name'],
        'apellido'  => $fbUserProfile['last_name'],
        'email'         => $fbUserProfile['email'],
        'genero'        => $fbUserProfile['gender'],
        'idioma'        => $fbUserProfile['locale'],
        'imagen'        => $fbUserProfile['picture']['url'],
        'url'           => $fbUserProfile['link']
    );
    $userData = $user->checkUser($fbUserData);

    // Put user data into session
    $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;

    // Redirect and render facebook profile data
    if(!empty($userData)){
        header('Location: usuario.php');
        exit;
    }else{
        $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
    }

}else{
    // Get login url
    $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);

    // Render facebook login url
    $output = '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($loginURL).'">Login with facebook</a>';
}

echo $output;
?>
```

**usuario.php (user profile)**

```
<?php
    // Activated the sessions
    session_start();

    // Render facebook profile data
    if(isset($_SESSION['userData'])){
        $userData = $_SESSION['userData'];
        echo '<h1>Perfil</h1>';
        echo '<img src="'.$userData['imagen'].'">';
        echo '<br/>Facebook ID : ' . $userData['id_fb'];
        echo '<br/>Nombre : ' . $userData['nombre'].' '.$userData['apellido'];
        echo '<br/>Email : ' . $userData['email'];
        echo '<br/>Genero : ' . $userData['genero'];
        echo '<br/>Idioma : ' . $userData['idioma'];
        echo '<br/><a href="'.$userData['url'].'" target="_blank">Ver perfil de usuario</a>';
        echo '<br/><br/><a href="salir.php">Salir</a>';
    }else{
        echo "Please login";
    }
?>
```

**admin.php (admin area)**

```
<?php
    // Activated the sessions
    session_start();

    // Check for admin
    if(isset($_SESSION['userData'])){
        $userData = $_SESSION['userData'];
        if ($userData['id_fb'] === 'MY_FB_ID_PROFILE') {
            echo "You are admin!";
        }else{
            echo "You are not admin";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Please login";
    }
?>
```

**salir.php (Get out)**

```
<?php
// Activated the sessions
session_start();

// Remove access token from session
unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

// Remove user data from session
unset($_SESSION['userData']);

// Redirect to the homepage
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: when in doubt, use a prepared statement and check for XSS exploits and "man in the middle" sessions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm researching right now, but then you recommend using the same "enter.php" code on the "profile" and "admin" page to avoid using sessions?

Comment: TBH; I've never used Facebook stuff so for that I couldn't say. If this is used inside an SSL socket, then that helps a lot; that I know.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I get it. Then, you know some alternative easy to implement (short code) to handle users, do not want to use laravel or something similar, are more than 5 thousand files and this is a very small project.